# Using grep in R with a * character to indicate an "anything" character

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with a column that looks like this:

```
par_ID <- c('x.m[1,1]','x.m[2,1]','x.m[1,2]','x.m[2,2]',
            'x.mm[1,1]','x.mm[2,1]','x.mm[1,2]','x.mm[2,2]',
            'alpha')
par_table <- data.frame(par_ID)
```

The positons in brackets represent where these values go in a matrix. I would like to extract all rows that begin with `x.m` with the motif `x.m[*,i]`, where `i` is a vector of parameter columns to loop over. Something like:

```
n <- 2
out.list <- list()
for(i in 1:n){
  out.list[[i]] <- par_table[grep(paste0('x.m[*,',i,']')),]
}
```

Which would return all rows with `x.m` preceding, and separate items in the list by the indicated column position.

The output would look like this:

```
output.list <- list(par_table[1:2,],par_table[3:4,])
```

Comment: Can you show the expected?  Do you need `par_table[grep("^x\\.m", par_table$par_ID),, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun sort of. That command returns both `x.m` and `x.mm` entries. Second, I would like each element of the list to be a separate column of the `x.m` data. so the first element would be rows `x.m[1,1]` and `x.m[2,1]`. The second element of the list would be the rows `x.m[1,2]`, `x.m[2,2]`.

Comment: Try `par_table[grep("^x\\.m\\[", par_table$par_ID),, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @akrun that isolates it to the `x.m` elements, but does not break out the `x.m[*,1]` from the `x.m[*,2]` rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `grep` to subset the elements with the pattern to match 'x' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by a dot (`.` is a metacharacter meaning any character, so escape (`\\.`) to evaluate it literally followed by a square bracket - again a metacharacter) and then create a grouping variable for `split`ting

```
out <- grep("^x\\.m\\[", par_table$par_ID, value = TRUE)
split(out, as.integer(gl(length(out), 2, length(out))))
```

If we want to split based on the pattern inside the bracket

```
split(out, as.integer(sub(".*\\[\\d+,(\\d+)\\]", "\\1", out)))
```